# My dryer has a issue after switching the breaker

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker

I sold my old dryer because my neighbor gave me a new dryer 
And her new dryer had a 4 prong plug compared to my old dryer which had a 3 prong plug...

I changed the 3 prong wire plug to the 4 prong dryer so it would plug into my outlet for the dryer... the dryer is on a 60 amp breaker by the way... and everything was fine the first couple of months then my breaker started getting hot, like too hot to touch kind of hot...

I switched off the breaker and switched it back on later and now the dryer won't work at all... my question is, would changing the wires on dryers cause a electrical malfunction in time and ruin something in the dryer by pulling to much current when the dryer had a 4 prong to start... ???

I found the 60 amp breaker odd for a dryer also, but no I can't post pictures... the dryer is too heavy for me to move and it's just a regular 3 prong dryer outlet , the wires were just changed from the dryer to the outlet...so it would work, and I didn't have to change the outlet.

Comment: "60 watt breaker"?!  And can you post photos of your dryer outlet?

Comment: If you have pictures, you can post them to [imgur](https://imgur.com) and post a link here

Comment: You should have changed the receptacle and rewired. Those 3-prong plugs kill people, and the reason might be related to your problem.  And yes, a 60 **amp** breaker is wrong for a dryer.

Answer (score 1):

I would say the main suspect is your breaker.

If it was heating up and not tripping it is probably faulty.

The normal breaker for a dryer circuit is 30 amp and #10 wire.

To use a 60 amp breaker for a dryer circuit you would need a minimum of #6 wire (smaller numbered wire is larger). I would suspect your wire is not that big.

If a voltage test at the outlet does not show voltage then you should try replacing the breaker with a 30 amp for a fairly inexpensive fix. If that doesn't work. It's possible the dryer needs repair.

Good luck and stay safe!